Could antineutron and pion generate proton?
We need information and guidance regarding the possibility of two reactions: antineutron + pi+ -> proton and antiproton + pi+ --> neutron. The attached illustration indicates that such reactions could be possible.


No, because the quark content is different.
Trying to keep it simple: In the last diagram, it's an antineutron $\bar{n}$ not a neutron since one $\bar{u}$ in the antiproton should annihilate with the $u$ of the positively charged pion which leaves us with 2$\bar{d}$'s and a single $\bar{u}$.
In the first diagram meanwhile the $u$ of the positively charged pion should annihilate with the $\bar{u}$ of the antineutron leaving you with the $Δ^-$ $($ $\bar{d}$$\bar{d}$$\bar{d}$$)$
